# Returning dates, between two dates (Gregorian Calender)

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

I'm creating a program which can take appointments. 
E.g. A doctors appointment, it will take name, number and date the appointment was created into an array.

if i want to check between date a and date b and see what appointments are between those dates how would i go about this?

I'm using the Gregorian Calendar

Comment: Just to be clear. You are not using Java 8? And showing some code wouldn't hurt at all ... a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be great

Comment: Both `Calendar` and `Date` have methods `after` and `before`.

Comment: Please, search Stack Overflow before posting. Tip: All the basic date-time questions have already been asked and answered.

Comment: “I'm using the `GregorianCalendar`”. Consider not doing that. The modern classes in the `java.time` package are much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the appointment dates in an array, you could use `Arrays.binarySearch(appoinments, a)` to find the first appointment on or after a, and similarly `Arrays.binarySearch(appoinments, b)` for the last appointment on or before b.